# My loop isn't working(using feof)

Tags: c, loops, feof

```
FILE *test;
student st;
int i = 0;
test = fopen("example.bin", "rb");
while (feof(test))
{
    fread(&st, sizeof(st),1,test);
    Class[i] = st;

    i++;
}
fclose(test);
```

So my question is how to read it, put the data in my structure and stop the loop?

Comment: What, specifically, is the misbehavior you observe?

Comment: But do note that your use of `feof()` is incorrect; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are trying to read a single student,  or you are trying to read all the students from the file?

Comment: ...in any case it would be `while (!feof(test))` but as commented either way is wrong.

Comment: in general, never use `feof()` for loop control.  In this case use the returned value from the call to `fread()` to control the loop.  The man page for `fread()` has the details on the returned value

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: this line: `Class[i] = st;` is only going to place a pointer to `st` in `Class[i]`.   Suggest using `memcpy( Class[i], st, sizeof(student) )'`

Comment: always check the returned value from a call to `fread()` to assure the operation was successful.  (if use `fread()` in while statement, it is the returned value that will actually control the loop)

Comment: in the posted code, the variable `Class[]` is not defined.  can we assume it is an array of `student`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [why is while(feof) always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Instead, you should loop until you fail to read a student:

```
while (1 == fread(&st, sizeof st, 1, test))
{
    Class[i++] = st;
}
```

Also it would be good to make sure you don't overflow the buffer of `Class`, so put in a check for `i` too, e.g.:

```
for (i = 0; i < MAX_CLASS && 1 == fread(&st, sizeof st, 1, test); ++i)
{
    Class[i] = st;
}
```

Comment: The assignment of `Class[i]` from `st` will not work in c (it might in c++) but this is not c++